# Error in simple shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm a beginner to shell scripts, and wrote below script but it keeps returning that "done" is not recognized token.

I know this is a super simple script, but I am too novice to debug this.. could anyone explain why this is not working? Thanks!

```
  #!/bin/sh

    for file in `ls`
    do
    if [ -f $file ]
            echo $file + " exists"
    fi
    done
```

comment: added fi, but still has an error: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'

Comment: but shell script doesn't require semicolons.

Comment: Also, I don't think `$file + " exists"`  will output what you expect, as it will print a literal "+" sign. You can simply write: `echo $file exists`. Or, if you want to make the message more explicit: `echo "$file exists"`.

Comment: @dsetton That's right, thanks!

Comment: @pandagrammer You may find [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net) useful. It tries to give more helpful error messages for these things.

Answer (score 2):

You miss the `then` (and your `echo` statement is probably malformed). Try:

```
#!/bin/sh

for file in `ls`
do
  if [ -f $file ]
  then
    echo "$file exists"
  fi
done
```